# Magento 2 Store View multiselect in system.xml

Tags: magento2.2.2, store-view, system.xml

I am not able to add store view selection in system.xml I am only able to add in the ui form field component:

When I tried to add in system.xml it gives the error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, 
array given in
.../vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/AbstractElement.php on line 287
```

**system.xml**:

```
<field id="store_view" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="13" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>Store view</label>
   <source_model>Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</source_model>
</field>
```

**form_edit.xml**

```
<field name="store">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options/item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

[image]

Is it possible at all the way magento has build this?

Answer (score 3):

I've found that this can be achieved by using class `Magento\Store\Model\System\Store`

```
<field id="store_view" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="13" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
      <label>Store View</label>
      <source_model>Magento\Store\Model\System\Store</source_model>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

**system.xml :-**

```
<field id="store_view" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="13" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>Store view</label>
   <source_model>vendor\module\Model\Source\Config\Option</source_model>
</field>
<?php
```

**option.php**

```
namespace vendor\module\Model\Source\Config;

class Option implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{

    protected $eavConfig;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }


    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $storeManagerDataList = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
        $options = array();

        foreach ($storeManagerDataList as $key => $value) {
               $options[] = array(
                'value' =>  $value['name'],
                'label' => $value['code'],
            );
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the answer. in need to show parent of store view also in similar fashion to the store view switcher, same as image attached in the question.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use the class "Magento\Store\Model\System\Store", see below:

```
 <field id="custom_store_field_id" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
      <label>Stores</label>
      <source_model>Magento\Store\Model\System\Store</source_model>
 </field>
```

Simple like that.